# How to limit the message stream interval of a web socket I connected to

Tags: websocket, limit, message

I dont think it is necessary to post my code here, but incase it is I have it below.

I am connected to coinbases websocket and trying to pull prices on coins but the message stream feeds me data many times per second, but I am looking to pull price data about  once a minute.

Can anyone help me understand how to limit a message stream using the WS node package?

```
const stream = new WebSocket('wss://ws-feed.exchange.coinbase.com')

stream.on('open', () => {
    stream.send(JSON.stringify({
        "type": "subscribe",
        "product_ids": [
            "BTC-USD"
        ],
        "channels": [
            {
                "name": "ticker",
                "product_ids": [
                    "BTC-USD"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }))
})


stream.on('message', (data) => {
    console.log('received: ', JSON.parse(data))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not close the connection after you receive your messages then reconnect after one minute?

```
<html>
    <body>

        <textarea rows="20" cols="100"  id="output"></textarea>

        <script>
            const output = document.querySelector('#output')
            const MAX = 5;               // receive 5 messages
            const INTERVAL =  60 *1000; // 1 minute                
            const URL = 'wss://ws-feed.exchange.coinbase.com';

            connect(URL);
                    
            function connect(addr) {                
                let counter = 0;   // Track number of msgs received
                let connection = new WebSocket(addr);

                // no change to your code
                connection.onopen = function() {
                    connection.send(JSON.stringify({
                        "type": "subscribe",
                        "product_ids": [
                            "BTC-USD"
                        ],
                        "channels": [
                            {
                                "name": "ticker",
                                "product_ids": [
                                    "BTC-USD"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }))
                };
                
                connection.onmessage =  function(event) {
                    output.value += `received: , ${ event.data}`;
                    counter++;
                    if ( counter == MAX ) {
                        counter = 0;    //reset counter
                        connection.close(); // no longer accept messages, 
                        output.value += "\n*******\n\n"
                        setTimeout( function() { connect(URL); }, INTERVAL);   // reconnect after interval
                    }
                    
                };        

            }
        
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```